# Check that specific font is installed or not?

Tags: fonts

I create a RTL website in Urdu language. Its also required "Alvi Nastaleeq" Urdu font to view correctly. How to check that visitor have such font installed or not? If the font is not fount, a message appear rather then website that says "This is website is completely compiled in Urdu. To see it please install Alvi Nastaleeq Font". How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this with javascript:  http://www.kirupa.com/html5/detect_whether_font_is_installed.htm

Code:

```
//
// Call this function and pass in the name of the font you want to check for availability.
//
function doesFontExist(fontName) {
    // creating our in-memory Canvas element where the magic happens
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // the text whose final pixel size I want to measure
    var text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    // specifying the baseline font
    context.font = "72px monospace";

    // checking the size of the baseline text
    var baselineSize = context.measureText(text).width;

    // specifying the font whose existence we want to check
    context.font = "72px '" + fontName + "', monospace";

    // checking the size of the font we want to check
    var newSize = context.measureText(text).width;

    // removing the Canvas element we created
    delete canvas;

    //
    // If the size of the two text instances is the same, the font does not exist because it is being rendered
    // using the default sans-serif font
    //
    if (newSize == baselineSize) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

doesFontExist("Comic Sans MS");
```

Comment: How to call function doesFontExist("Comic Sans MS"); is jsfiddle?